# aws sts get-caller-identity not displaying expected account

Tags: aws-cli, git-bash

I have some troubles with a docker container regarding aws accountId. A lot of commands fail with the same error message : *unable to get local certificate*

With a bit of poking around, I found that my local aws credentials were compromised, so I generated a new access key : **########3PX**

I updated my .aws/credentials files lmike this :

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=########3PX
aws_secret_access_key=########
```

On the console, I manually re-configured the user, just to be sure :

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************W3PX]: ########3PX
AWS Secret Access Key [****************c9ip]: ################
Default region name [eu-west-1]: 
Default output format [json]:
```

and yet, when I type the command `aws sts get-caller-identity`, I still get another account :

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "####I3T",
    "Account": "####950",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::####950:user/me"
}
```

The account id is correct, the arn is correct, but the UserId is wrong.

I can't find anywhere on my machine where this *####I3T** userId is defined :

- aws cli is configured with ####3PX id
- my env script doesn't export variables anymore, thay are commented out (and still, they set the values to the 3PX account)

Do you guys have any idea how to correct the settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is an order how AWS cli looks into credentials. You might have multiple conflicting configurations. First you should check if you have AWS_PROFILE exported. What is usually do is that I do not use default in the credentials file, so I cannot accidentally use the default credentials and make sure that I force the profile use.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Access Key ID and UserId are two different things.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html

> When IAM creates a user, user group, role, policy, instance profile,
> or server certificate, it assigns a unique ID to each resource. The
> unique ID looks like this:
>
> AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q
>
> For the most part, you use friendly names and ARNs when you work with
> IAM resources. That way you don't need to know the unique ID for a
> specific resource.
>
> ...
>
> The unique ID for an IAM resource is not available in the IAM console.
> To get the unique ID, you can use the following AWS CLI commands or
> IAM API calls.